# How do I integrate Multer and Multer-S3 with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3

I have decided to go the S3 route for storing images instead of doing it with Gridfs. But I am still confused as to how MongoDB will integrate with Multer and S3.

For instance, lets say I have a collection of documents for each user.  It's assumed that the documents themselves won't contain the profile pics that will get uploaded to my S3 cloud.

But when I display a list of users in the front-end, how can I make sure that the correct profile pic is displayed for each user?

I am looking over the multer-s3 documentation, and I notice that metadata sets the name of the file that is to be uplaoded to S3 (I think?).

```
var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'some-bucket',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {fieldName: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})
```

I am thinking maybe a good solution to this problem would be name each file that is uploaded as the same name as the user who will use it. Can I tinker with the metadata and key functions so that they are the same name as the username of whoever uploads them? What exactly does `cb` do and what does each of it paramters represent?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the username of the user, you can name the file by changing the key.

```
key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, username + ".jpg")
}
```

Or you could put photo files inside of a file folder like this:

```
key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, username + "/profile.jpg")
}
```

Inclusion of the / will allow you to create and put images in folders.